# Laravel: Best way to have multiple user relations on same model

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-9

I have a polling app.

Admins can create new polls. I have a belongsTo relation in my polls Model so I can later track which user created the poll.

Now I want to allow the poll admin to add users from the list of registered users so that only these users can access the poll.

Adding another hasMany relation to users to the poll model does not work because it already has the belongsTo. But what would the best way be? Simply add a field to my poll model and fill it with a list of user ids? Auth? But does that make sense for possibly hundreds of polls?

I feel like I am not seing an obvious solution here...

Thanks

Poll Model

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Poll extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $guarded = [];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

}
```

User model

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;
use Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable, HasRoles;

     ...

    /**
     * poll relationship
     */

    public function polls()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Poll::class);
    }
}
```

Poll migration

```
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('polls', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestamp('start_time')->nullable();
            $table->timestamp('end_time')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->index('user_id');
        });
    }
}
```

User migration

```
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73807047/edit) and include the current code for your `User` and `Poll` models? And maybe your database tables (i.e. the migrations); might help if we can see what you're trying to do instead of inferring it from a description.

Comment: @TimLewis its a very very simple test app, see above

Comment: @JaNosch what you are looking for is "Pivot tables (many to many relations)" https://laraveldaily.com/pivot-tables-and-many-to-many-relationships/

Comment: @OnurUslu Pivot = belongsTonMany, right? But won't belongsToMany on the poll model clash with the already existing belongsTo for the user who created the poll?

Comment: @JaNosch `belongsTo`and `belongsToMany` completely different things. In `belongsToMany`relationship, you need to create a new table with `poll_id`and `user_id` columns. Thanks to this table structure, you can make many to many relations.

Comment: What do you need? Expected? All polls with users?

Comment: @OnurUslu yes I know. But how can I have BOTH these relations on the SAME Models. I want belongsTo for the user creating the poll AND belongsToMany for the users that can access the poll.

Comment: @AbdullaNilam Please see my original post as well as my comment above, I explain what I want there.

Comment: @JaNosch You can have two relations in your model by using two methods. For example, in the poll model, there should be `creator()` and `participants()` methods. The first method returns the `BelongsTo` relation; the second returns the `BelongsToMany` relation.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to create a a different, [many to many](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) relationship between polls and users. I call it `participants`.

```php
table poll_user
    poll_id
    user_id

class Poll extends Model
{
    public function participants()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'poll_user');
    }
}
```